# Unpacking values of current function value and array from fmin scipy optimisation

Tags: python, scipy

```
def getMaxDeflection(self):
    def func(x): return self.getTotalDeflection(x)
    a = s.fmin(lambda x: -func(x), 0)
    return a
```

This returns

```
>>> b.getMaxDeflection()
 Optimization terminated successfully.
 Current function value: -0.004343
 Iterations: 28
 Function evaluations: 56
 Out[161]: array([ 2.7473125])
```

As you can see I end up with current function value of -0.004343 and array output of 2.7473. I would like to end up with an tuple of (0.004343, 2.7473) but am not quite sure how to go about it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L290) and the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html), you need to do the following:

```
def getMaxDeflection(self):
    a = s.fmin(lambda x: -self.getTotalDeflection(x), 0, full_output=1)
    return a[1], a[0][0]
```

The values `fopt, iter, funcalls, warnflag` will only be added to the output if `full_output` is set to True. Additionally, if you set `disp=0`, you will also prevent the convergence messages from being printed.

Comment: Sorted. Thanks very much :)